# Partial order on the orbits of the variety of commuting nilpotent matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, integer-partitions, group-actions

The variety of nilpotent $n\times n$ matrices $\mathcal{N}_n$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ is the disjoint union of orbits under the action of conjugation by $GL_n(k)$.  These orbits are characterized by the Jordan form.  Since all eigenvalues of a nilpotent matrix are zero, the data of the Jordan form of a nilpotent $n\times n$ matrix is equivalent to a partition of $n$.

If we place a partial order on the orbits of $\mathcal{N}_n$ by $\mathcal{O}\le\mathcal{O}'$ if and only if $\overline{\mathcal{O}}\subset\overline{\mathcal{O}'}$, then it turns out that the partial order on the orbits corresponds to the dominance ordering on partitions.

Now, suppose that $\mathcal{C}_2(\mathcal{N}_n)$ is the variety of commuting ordered pairs of nilpotent $n\times n$ matrices.  $GL_n$ still acts by conjugation component-wise, and we can place the same partial order on orbits mentioned above.  Namely $\mathcal{O}\le\mathcal{O}'$ if and only if $\overline{\mathcal{O}}\subset\overline{\mathcal{O}'}$.  As in the previous case, is there a description of the partial order in terms of partitions?  Does anybody know of a reference where this question is considered?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.2304v3.pdf. This paper seems relevant. Not exactly what you want but very close results that I think you'd be interested in, for example, Lemma 2.22.